# Laravel Resource controller not getting delete route on amchor click

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

In laravel, I have resource controller :

```php
Route::resource('/student','StudentController');
```

here is my view listing code :

```php
<tr>
    <td>{{ $key + $models->firstItem() }}</td>
    <td>{{ $model->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $model->email }}</td>
    <td>{{ $model->roll_no }}</td>
    <td>{{ $model->StudentDetail->phone }}</td>
    <td>{{ $model->StudentDetail->course }}</td>
    <td>{{ $model->StudentDetail->city }}</td>
    <td>{{ $model->StudentDetail->state->state_name }}</td>
    <td>
        <a href="#">Edit</a> |
        <a href="{{ route('student.destroy', ['id' => $model->id]) }}">Link</a>

    </td>
</tr>
```

conytroller function i have :

```php
public function destroy($id)
{
   echo "ok";
}
```

> My problem is that when I click on anchor button(delete ) it not
>   found the resource route for the delete what I am doing wrong here can
>   anyone please help me elated this.
>   when I click on the delete anchor it calls the show function of resource but I want the destroy function to call on click.

Comment: Method of the route is post, but you're sending a `get` request

Comment: so how can we use resource destroy method for anchor delete ..

Answer (score 0):

`destroy` function use `DELETE` method

in your blade view

```
@foreach($students as $model)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $key + $models->firstItem() }}</td>
    <td>{{ $model->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $model->email }}</td>
    <td>{{ $model->roll_no }}</td>
    <td>{{ $model->StudentDetail->phone }}</td>
    <td>{{ $model->StudentDetail->course }}</td>
    <td>{{ $model->StudentDetail->city }}</td>
    <td>{{ $model->StudentDetail->state->state_name }}</td>
    <td>
        <a href="#">Edit</a> |

        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="event.preventDefault();document.getElementById('delete_form').submit();">DELETE</a>

       <form id="delete_form" style="display:none" action="{{ route('student.destroy',$model->id)}}" method="POST" >
          {{ csrf_field() }}   
           <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete" />
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: your code is generating this url :4l1MnfsHwCZMbST1B3b139p9XJMY7xam&_method=DELETE&_method=delete&id=1  but not going on destroy function

Comment: how can i get echo "ok" of destroy function after click on anchor link

Comment: add method and action to form

Comment: now it redirecting me to the destroy function but for every anchor it showing the id 1 only..

Comment: updated answer , please check now , update action in form

Comment: in each table row , you have to create hidden form for different id of students .

Comment: have you added this to form ` action="{{ route('student.destroy',$model->id)}}"`